# Please unlock and open question 125122

Tags: support, reopen-request

With reference to question [How to get live status of train in a website?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125122/), I would like to reopen it and rephrase it.

The title could be: How to get the live status of an Indian train?

There are 2 answers:
1. Official PNR enquiry website: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/enquiry/PNR/PnrEnquiry.html?locale=en. After entering your PNR, you can check live status, seating charts etc.
2. On Etrain.info private website where schedule and live running status (refreshed every few minutes) can be checked. Example: https://etrain.info/in?TRAIN=14258

In my last trip to India, I was asked several times by foreigners about it and I think it is a very useful piece of information when traveling in India on trains.

Though the question is about the API integration, the question behind it is still relevant to travelers.

Thanks,
Ritesh

Comment: The question was deleted as spam (which automatically deleted it and locked it), but was later undeleted. However, the undeleting moderator didn't also remove the lock.

Comment: Unlocked and re-opened. Ritesh, up to you to edit it so it can stay open.

Comment: Thank you so much @Willeke. I have edited the question and also added an answer.